Reducing GCP DataStream Sync Latency from PostgreSQL to BigQuery
I'm using GCP DataStream to sync data from PostgreSQL to BigQuery. However, I've noticed a delay of just over ten minutes in the data sync process. After digging into the documentation, I found that the issue is likely due to the default max_staleness configuration for the BigQuery destination tables. By default, the max_staleness is set to 1 hour, which causes the data to be delayed.
I've tried setting the max_staleness to 5 minutes to reduce the sync latency, but I'm concerned about the potential increase in query costs. Here's the command I used:
ALTER TABLE `to_be_synced.table` SET OPTIONS (max_staleness = INTERVAL 5 MINUTE);

Can anyone confirm if this is the correct approach to reduce the sync latency, and if there are any other potential issues or considerations I should be aware of?
